# Migration path to gaming.SE?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I wanted to vote to close [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1363/252) of me to be migrated to http://gaming.stackexchange.com, but there are no migration paths available, so I request

> A migration path to gaming.SE

This sounds sensible since every now and then a gaming question might end up here, or be at least very borderline like [mine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1363/252).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a Gaming question, for starters. At Gaming, we don't handle mod development and map development. Gaming and Game Dev had an early discussion that marked them the subject of Game Dev, not Gaming. And, to wit, haha, [you started that discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here).

As mentioned by ChrisF in the comments, if you want a migration path, you need to provide *ample* amounts of evidence. Questions that have been migrated to Gaming, for example, or ones that *should* be migrated to us. Ample means a fair amount - you need to prove that people *are* coming here with the wrong questions, not simply that they might.

At present, **0** questions have been migrated to Gaming from this site. Comparatively, we have sent 7 questions over here. Gaming doesn't have an opened path, either, because 7 is a pretty piddling number.

Until you actually become inundated with Gaming questions, the migration path is unnecessary. A moderator flag should be sufficient to migrate them when appropriate.

Comment: you got me there... thanks for reminding me. Too bad the downvotes on my question don't indicate consents, but maybe I'm misinterpreting that

Comment: @Tobias The majority of downvotes came before the discussion on whether mod/map questions were acceptable here. So I think they're just artifacts, for the most part. I can't explain the August downvote, but eh, you can't please everyone I s'pose. ♪

Comment: true, and neither should one try to do so :-7 Oh well, I guess I can still find my sleep...

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime you can flag the question for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated.

Moderators can migrate to any other site on the network.

Comment: since I get a "you have already flagged this question" I seem to have tried that some time ago, although I can't remember when...

Comment: @Tobias - ah, then asking here is the next step!

Comment: exactly. especially since I noticed there is not even a _single_ migration path available at all (besides meta of course)

Comment: @Tobias - if you can find evidence of a need (I can see SO and Gaming as obvious ones) and post it as an answer here the team will take notice and add the path. A moderator can help by being able to review the questions that have been manually migrated.