# How should we tag modding questions?

Tags: discussion

Today, I noticed a few mod questions that didn't really have any tags pertaining or indicating they were mod related. I noticed we already had a description-less "mods" tag, so I edited it to add some information.

Should we tag existing and older questions with the tag "mods" or is there a better way to identify these?

[It seems like they are in scope of this site, unless the community has changed their mind. Although, I've noticed they do not receive much attention.](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the community has accepted these as a part of our Stack Exchange platform, I believe strongly that it makes sense to categorize these together so that it is clear when the author has identified their question is mod related. In doing so, we can group them all together and get a better idea of the popularity of such questions and how well they fit into the community.

By doing this, we can gain valuable insight and metrics on how well our community is versed in handling these specific types of questions while allowing those who are well versed in mods to look up and answer.

I also propose some synonyms, such as: modding and others that might fit the bill.

Comment: Tagging old questions with appropriate tags is generally acceptable and desired (although, as a note to anybody who wants to go tag-crazy, that old questions usually have other problems you should try to address when editing; don't just re-tag if you can also improve other aspects of the question). I squashed `modding` into `mods`.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Thanks, I made a head start on some of it but I have other stuff to do for now. If nobody else gets around to it tonight, I'll start going through them.

"Skyrim", "Starcraft" and other popular game names are probably a way to start filtering these out.

Comment: @JoshPetrie It seems like you killed the description with it, is it possible to restore this?

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, that seems to happen (I presume it's a bug). Let me see if I can restore it.

Comment: Okay. I think I unbroke it.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Thanks, Josh. Seems fixed.